# Showing that a morphism is an equivalence relation

Tags: category-theory, equivalence-relations, morphism

> Let $\mathscr{C}$ be a category. $X,Y \in ob(\mathscr{C})$, $X$ and $Y$ are said to be equivalent if there is an equivalence $f:X \rightarrow Y$. Show this is an equivalence relation.

For the equivalence $f:X \rightarrow Y$ we know that there exists a $g: Y \rightarrow X$ such that $g \circ f= {id}_{X}, f \circ g={id}_{Y}$.

I'm not too sure how to show this is an equivalence relation but have got the following:
Let ~ be the equivalence relation on X such that $x~y \Rightarrow f(x)=f(y)$.
We can then see this relation is:
reflexive since f~f 
symmetric since $g(f(x))=x$ ~ $y=f(g(y))$ 
transistive for x~y, y~z 
$f(x)=f(y), f(y)=f(z) \Rightarrow f(x)=f(z)$ so x~z

Is this the right way to prove the morphism equivalence relation?

Comment: This is not the right way at all. The equivalence relation should be on the family of objects in the category, not on a single object. You should show reflexivity, transitivity and symmetry on the objects, i.e. for reflexivity, take $X\in ob(\mathcal{C})$ and show there is an equivalence $X\to X$. You will be using the definition of a category multiple times in a correct proof.

Comment: Okay that's helpful thank you. So by the definition of category it is easy to prove transitivity since for $X,Y,Z \in ob(\mathscr{C})$ we have the composition of morphisms being that $(f: X \rightarrow Y) \times (f: Y \rightarrow Z) \rightarrow (f:X \rightarrow Z)$ so our transitive property is show. How do you go about symmetry and reflexiveness?

Comment: My mind-reading machine suggest that in the question *equivalence* should be *isomorphism*, and that the problem is: how do I show that the isomorphism relation on objects is an equivalence relation.

Comment: You have to be slightly more careful; You want that if $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to Z$ are both isomorphisms, then there exists an isomorphism $h:X\to Z$. You are right that you need to use composition, i.e. one of the axioms of a category, but you need to show that $h=g\circ f$ is actually an isomorphism. For reflexivity, what morphisms are we guaranteed to have in a category, and are they isomorphisms? For symmetry, look at the definition of an isomorphism - it requires the existence of another function, which might be helpful. I'll give you some more time to look at this yourself.

Comment: Thank you! We will have the identity morphism to help with reflexivity and the inverse function g for symmetry.